# Raspberry Pi Touchscreen doesn't work with Windows 10

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen, windows

I have a Raspberry Pi Touchscreen connected to my Raspberry Pi. It worked perfectly with Raspbian but with Windows 10 it doesnt.

I've done all the Windows Updates and don't know what to do to make it work again.

Has anyone ever experienced something like that?

And if you have how did you solve it?

Comment: Windows is not supported on the Pi - so the Pi foundation is unlikely to provide a driver.

Comment: yes, I have experienced something like that ... is that all you wanted to know?

Comment: @jsotola well did you find a way to make it work?